# I am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, hibernate-mapping, querydsl

I couldn't execute this query in hibernate JPA QueryDSL using @Query method.. While using this query in my repository, it gives the following exception, 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException'..

```
 @Query("SELECT id,date,customer_id, SUM(price) AS price, GROUP_CONCAT(description ORDER BY customer_id DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS description, category FROM #{#entityName} e WHERE product_id = :productId GROUP BY category")
  public Iterable<Product> findByProductId(@Param("productdId") int productId);
```

How to execute this one? Is it correct? Or Do I have to do any other logic?

Comment: Full stacktrace please.